# Android Why Fragment save viewState by itself?

Tags: android, fragment

I am using fragment by *supportFragmentManager*

When I move to some Fragment and write down text in EditText, then go back(without any saving), and move again to that Fragment, EditText fill with I write down before.

I don't want to save the EditText state, but it save by itself....

Additionally, some Fragments don't save their viewState but other some Fragments save it.

The Fragment don't save their viewState are located first depth on Activity which means they are home screen at each tab.

On the other hand, The Fragment save their viewState by itself located second or more depth from first depth fragment(home screen)

This is FragmentNavigation code

```
class FragmentNavigation(private val activity: MainActivity) {

private val manager = activity.supportFragmentManager

private val fragmentMap = HashMap<Int, Stack<Fragment>>()
private var currentTab = 1  //This start destination fragment
private val container = R.id.nav_host_fragment

init {    //I have 5 tabs
    fragmentMap[0] = Stack<Fragment>()
    fragmentMap[1] = Stack<Fragment>().apply { push(MemoFragment()) }   //add starting point
    fragmentMap[2] = Stack<Fragment>()
    fragmentMap[3] = Stack<Fragment>()
    fragmentMap[4] = Stack<Fragment>()
}


fun change(info: FragmentInfo) =   //When user click bottomTab
    fragmentMap[info.tag]?.let {
        currentTab = info.tag

        if (it.isEmpty()) {
            it.push(info.fragment)

            manager.commit {
                replace(container, info.fragment)
            }
            return@let
        }

        //show last fragment I visited
        manager.commit {
            replace(container, it.last())
        }
    }

fun move(info: FragmentInfo) =     //When user move to second or more depth fragment
    fragmentMap[info.tag]?.let {

        it.push(info.fragment)
        manager.commit {
            replace(container, info.fragment)
        }
    }

fun back() =
    if(fragmentMap[currentTab]?.size == 1)
        activity.finishApp()
    else
        popFragment()

private fun popFragment() =
    fragmentMap[currentTab]?.let {
        it.pop()

        manager.commit {
            replace(container, it.peek())
        }
    }
}
```

As above code say, first depth Fragments(don't save state) are shown by *change function*,
problematic fragment(save state) are shown by *move function*.

-> There is no **onSaveInstanceState** function in fragment.

-> Not using **Bundle**

-> I tried **add** and **remove** instead of **replace** as a *fragmentTransaction*, but same result..

-> tried remove all viewModel

-> Not using **DataBinding**

-> Tried Invalidate Cashes/Restart, Clean project, Rebuild Project many time.

-> remove and reinstall app so many time.

Comment: I am surprised the state is saved at all - are the EditText the same when you rotate the screen? It seems to me that with this setup they should be empty after screen rotation

Comment: @Stachu Yes... The EditText is same when rotate the screen. It looks Somewhere save the viewState.

Comment: and you are not using ViewModel or anything else aware of the LifeCycle?

Comment: I am using viewModel with Koin, but when I use viewModel normally(not Koin DI), the problematic result is same!  OK now I am going to remove all viewModel in my project, and then try.

Comment: @Stachu Even if I remove all the viewModels, same hahhahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahah What the heck is going on

Comment: it seems impossible, no data binding etc? if you create a new fragment with just edit text - does it hold value on rotation?

Comment: @Stachu Yep No databinding, And I made new Fragment with EditText as a test, It doesn't save text state, so when rotate screen the text is gone.. It must be save viewState by something in Fragment I made before.

Comment: I just removed all code in the fragment which make auto saving problem, so now it is same with test Fragment, BUT IT STILL SAVE TEXT. It looks kinda bug